# mod-rewrite rules grabs "broken permalinks", too

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is the automatically generated htaccess file of WP using permalinks for the pattern `/%year%/%postname%/` (working with `http://localhost/BLOG-FOLDER/` yet):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /BLOG-FOLDER/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /BLOG-FOLDER/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now the problem is that the rewrite rule applies for `http://localhost/BLOG-FOLDER/this-file-does-not-exist`, too, and not only for "correct permalinks" such as `http://localhost/2012/My-first-entry/`.

So, what are the modifications of my htaccess file to get this work?

Thanks a lot!
Carlos

Comment: Your question is very vague and does not explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Give us examples, what do you want it to do if the page doesn't exist? What about if the page does exist?

Answer (score 1):

The web server doesn’t know if a request URI matches a valid permalink.

Handling 404 errors happens in WordPress itself. Your theme should have a `404.php` file to return properly formatted output.